# Docker.service start error

Tags: docker

Recently, I rebuild a nginx container with a Dockerfile. But it said Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container aa_php: Cannot link to a non running container: /img AS /nginx/php. So i try systemctl restart docker.service. it fails!

```
sh$ uname -a
Linux izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sh$ docker version
Client:
Version: 17.10.0-ce
API version: 1.33
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: f4ffd25
Built: Tue Oct 17 19:04:05 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

sh$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?


-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23.396022007+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: starte
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" module=con
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="changing OOM score to -500" mod
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.c
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.s
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.con
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.s
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.m
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter bt
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.d
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.m
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.r
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.g
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/doc
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/doc
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23+08:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos dockerd[11830]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: /var/lib/docker contains
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 12:30:23 VM_0_15_centos systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

I cant start docker.service after using `systemctl restart docker.service`.   Before doing this, the docker service works well on my servers.

I tried to add `{ "storage-driver": "devicemapper" }` to the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. The docker service can be started. But the docker images and the containers are all missing.

```
sh$ df -h
[docker]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        50G   18G   30G  38% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G   24K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  356K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/0
```

tmpfs           380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/1000

On the other hand, when I remove `{ "storage-driver": "devicemapper" }` from `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. And then I do `mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker_cp`. The docker service can also be started. But all the docker images and containers are missing.

So how to start the docker service with exists images and containers?

```
sh$ ls /var/lib/docker
drwx--x--x   15 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x.  37 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:50 ..
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Nov 13 00:50 builder
drwx--x--x    3 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:12 containerd
drwx------    8 root root   4096 Dec  2 11:42 containers
drwx------    4 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:26 devicemapper
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 187634 Dec  2 12:31 dockerd[11830]: time="2017-12-02T12:30:23.396022007+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: starte
drwx------    4 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:24 image
drwxr-x---    3 root root   4096 Nov 13 00:50 network
drwx------  133 root root  32768 Dec  2 12:53 overlay
drwx------    4 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:53 plugins
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:53 runtimes
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Nov 13 00:50 swarm
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:53 tmp
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Nov 13 00:50 trust
drwx------    2 root root   4096 Nov 13 00:50 volumes

sh$ journalctl -u docker | tail -n 200
 ew containerd process, pid: 26277"
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26271]: time="2017-12-02T14:19:06.223706271+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26271]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 02 14:19:06 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26289]: time="2017-12-02T14:19:06.627836666+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: n          ew containerd process, pid: 26295"
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26289]: time="2017-12-02T14:19:07.634725753+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26289]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 02 14:19:07 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26307]: time="2017-12-02T14:19:07.877330414+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: n          ew containerd process, pid: 26313"
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26307]: time="2017-12-02T14:19:08.884387445+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26307]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:19:08 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:19:09 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:19:09 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Dec 02 14:19:09 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:19:09 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:19:09 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:22:51 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 02 14:22:51 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26362]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:51.286002990+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: n          ew containerd process, pid: 26368"
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26362]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:52.292699326+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26362]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 02 14:22:52 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26379]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:52.625319452+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: n          ew containerd process, pid: 26385"
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26379]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:53.634927699+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26379]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 02 14:22:53 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26397]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:53.877175810+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: n          ew containerd process, pid: 26403"
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26397]: time="2017-12-02T14:22:54.884380750+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] us          ing prior storage driver: overlay"
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz dockerd[26397]: Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:22:54 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Dec 02 14:22:55 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 14:22:55 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Dec 02 14:22:55 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 02 14:22:55 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 14:22:55 izwz94xswj2tx8086sbgnrz systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```